# Where do I place my C# code in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I only ever had experience in using webforms but I have started learning MVC4 recently to broaden my knowledge. However as someone with only experience in webforms, It took me awhile go get a grip on MVC4.

I've basically set up the displays for the site with the layouts and views and calling the views with the controller.

However I want to move on and start giving the site a purpose, like registration etc. which requires some heavy c# coding.

However I am lost on where I should place my handlers etc. I figured I should do my data connection and all behind-page processes in the controller?

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: read tutorials on asp.nect mvc first before starting coding

Comment: This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En) can help you understanding architecture of MVC application.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you can put your c# code wherever you want. The only conventions that MVC adheres to by default are the `Controllers` and `Views` folder. And technically the only reason for the `Controllers` folder is because controllers placed in there will default to the `MyApp.Controllers` namespace. Controllers are resolved by name and namespace, not file location (unlike Views).

What I usually do is put business specific services in a `Services` folder, and utility/infrastructure in an `Infrastructure` folder.

However, you're free to arrange your c# code however you like.

Comment: +1 To this because of good, clear information. To add to this, OP, I'd recommend you read up on "Onion Architecture". Start with [Jeffrey Palermo's introduction](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) and go from there. It really helped me understand how to structure MVC apps in a useful way.

Comment: friend is it good for your c# code directly put in View ??rather we use 
Ajax. 

is it effect on page performance ???

Answer (score 3):

MVC (Model View Controller).

Your all data access logic code in "Model".
Your view and UI in "View".
Your all business logic code in "Controller".

In order for them to interact with each other. here is a simple example:

Your Model code:

```
public static List<string> GetCountryData()
{
    List<string> lstCountries = new List<string>();
    var countryData = yourDBContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SPROC_GetCountryData");

    if(countryData.Any())
    {
        lstCountries = countryData.ToList<string>();
    }
    return lstCountries;
}
```

Your Controller code:

```
public ActionResult CountryView()
{
    List<string> lstCountries = YourModel.GetCountryData();

    return View(lstCountries);
}
```

Your View:

```
@model List<string>

<ul>
@foreach (var country in @Model)
{
     <li>country</li>
}
</ul>
```

Hope it will help some.